# Parsing Multiple Argument Line

Tags: c, parsing, command-line-arguments, getopt

I'm actually in trouble, I would like to parse multiple arguments line like those one :

```
./a.out -a 0 L
./a.out -ab
./a.out -abc
```

I tried to did it with getopt but I didn't succeed. The fact is that I can't handle the multiple argument like

```
./a.out -abc
./a.out -edg
```

Is there any way of doing it the way I want with a function like getopt?

Or should I consider doing (with getopt):

```
./a.out -a -b
./a.out -a -b -c
```

Comment: What problem you got while trying to use getopt?

Comment: The probleme is that :

    "./a.out -a 0 J"
is the first option of my program which take two arguments.

    "./a.out -abc"
Is an another option which doesn't take anything else that the parameters after the '-'. So my problem is that I actually can't combine both of them for parsing my command line.

Comment: Why you need 2 parameters? Why don't use a different syntax? i.e: "./a -a 0,J -abc"

Comment: About the parameters : "./a.out -a 0" is for reading a specific entry (given with the parameters, where it would return the 0 entry) in my database. When "./a.out -ab" return all the entry in the database

Comment: And what's the "J" for?

Comment: J was an example.
Each entry in the database has a key:value system.
"./a.out -r 0 J" change the value for the key 0 to J.

Comment: Why not using something like 0:J?

Comment: Yeah but this would work only for this specific query, not others so I don't think it's the right solution for me

Comment: And why not using quotes?
"A J"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"a::" makes -a with optional arguments. -a by itself sets the `options` flag to get two seperate arguments. -aopt with attached options accepts `opt`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int c = 0;
    int each = 0;
    int options = 0;

    if ( !( argc == 2 || argc == 4)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage:\t%s -aopt\n or\n\t%s -a opt1 opt2\n", argv[0], argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }
    while((c = getopt(argc, argv, "a::")) != -1) {

        switch(c) {
            case 'a':
                if ( optarg) {// -aopt
                    printf ( "%s\n", optarg);
                }
                else {
                    options = 1;// -a by itself
                }
                break;
            default:
                fprintf(stderr, "Usage:\t%s -aopt\n or\n\t%s -a opt1 opt2\n", argv[0], argv[0]);
                return 1;
        }
    }
    if ( optind + 2 == argc) {
        if ( options) {
            for ( each = optind; each < argc; each++) {
                if ( ( argv[each][0] != '-')) {
                    printf ( "found argument %s\n", argv[each]);
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            fprintf(stderr, "Usage:\t%s -aopt\n or\n\t%s -a opt1 opt2\n", argv[0], argv[0]);
            return 1;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This was exactly the thing I was looking for, thanks so much !!